# Struts2 submit button method call doesn't fire

Tags: java, struts2

I am having problems with the below code, can anyone explain why the method may not be being fired on the jobListAction? 'Setup' is being called twice upon submission of the form.  In short, I can't seem to get the struts button to call multiple methods. Any pointers / things to check?

```
public class JobListAction {
    public String execute() {
        System.out.println("setup");
    }

    public String deactivate() {
        System.out.println("called");
    }
   public String callonme()
   {
   }
}
```

JSP:

```
<s:form id="recordsListForm" method="post" action="jobList">
 <s:submit type="button" action="deactivate" value="Deactivate Selected Jobs" method="deactivate" />
 <s:submit type="button" action="callonme" value="CallonMe" method="callonme" />

</s:form>
```

Struts.xml

```
    <!-- Job List -->
    <action name="jobList" class="JobListAction">
        <result name="input">/jsp/admin/jobList.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/jsp/admin/jobList.jsp</result>
    </action>

    <!-- Job List - Deactivate Job -->
    <action name="deactivate" class="JobListAction" method="deactivate">
        <result name="input">/jsp/admin/jobList.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/jsp/admin/jobList.jsp</result>
    </action>

    <action name="callonme" class="JobListAction" method="callonme">
        <result name="input">/jsp/admin/jobList.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/jsp/admin/jobList.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

Comment: Again, all this shouldn't be necessary... and won't work, because now you have a bunch of definitions for the same URL: how would it know which action def to call for "/jobList"? Action names need to be unique, because it's what's used to figure out what action/method to call.

Comment: @DaveNewton - tried an alternative solution with unique names for the action, and specifying on the submit action method. Still no juice.

Comment: Without the info I asked for in my answer, I'm not sure how to help--wasn't asking just to take up space. But now you're defining the method in *both* the submit button *and* the action config, and I doubt that'd work, although I've never tried it, because it's redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess in struts 2 u need to tell the method name in Struts.xml file, try that out, I hope it works...

```
<action name="jobList" class="JobListAction" method = "deactivate">
  <result name="input">/jsp/admin/jobList.jsp</result>
  <result name="success">/jsp/admin/jobList.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: you legend. looks like it does indeed need the method defined in the struts file. By 'multiple methods' I meant I'm going to need a couple of submit buttons on the same page, talking to different methods, but wanted to get this working first.

Comment: @Paul No, it *doesn't* need the method defined in the Struts file. It *works*, but is not required.

Comment: In this particular instance, there was already an identical XML declaration for the Action. As such, defining as you have written (I'm guessing) has overridden that initial declaration, and thus the method gets called. But hey-  If it works, it works!

Comment: @Paul (Use the @ thing for replying, otherwise the intended recipient won't see it.) Don't know what you're saying; if you're using DMI you'd only have a single definition for an action.

Comment: @DaveNewton you are right, when I add the additional method declaration, the tower comes tumbling down. Ideally I want the first <!--Job list--> declaration to stand, but the JSP determine what method should be called on each button. As such, the method can't be specified in the Struts file?

Comment: @Paul And commented; still seems like it'd be easier to follow through on figuring out the actual problem, but if you insist on putting the method names in the config file, just have a unique action name per action def.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have a single action declaration that can call multiple methods in the same action class, look into using [wilcard mappings](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.6/docs/action-configuration.html#ActionConfiguration-WildcardMethod):

**View**

```
<s:form id="recordsListForm" method="post" action="jobList">
   <s:submit type="button" action="jobList_deactivate" value="Deactivate Jobs" />
   <s:submit type="button" action="jobList_callonme" value="CallonMe" />
</s:form>
```

**struts.xml**

```
<!-- Job List -->
<action name="jobList_*" method="{1}" class="JobListAction">
    <result name="input">/jsp/admin/jobList.jsp</result>
    <result name="success">/jsp/admin/jobList.jsp</result>
</action>
```

The above mapping will match any `action` that starts with `jobList_` and then use the rest of the match as the method to call in the `JobListAction` class.

Comment: Certainly works, but not *necessary* using dynamic method invocation. Plus you don't need to set the "method" attribute in the submit buttons using this; the action name should be enough, no?

Comment: @DaveNewton good catch, removed the `method` attribute on the submit buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me; what version? Is dynamic method invocation enabled (it is by default)?

What do you mean by "call *multiple* methods?" You can only call a single method per-request.

My stdout:

```
setup // On initial form display
called // Clicking submit
```

Cut-and-pasted your code (more or less) verbatim.